# Feature Request : Configuration preference for single best match. MusicID

Tags: gracenote

I have been using the mobile developer kit for a couple of weeks and I have tested the "GNOperations.recognizeMIDFileFromFile" method from the android kit on a large number of files with single best match response configured. I was pretty impressed with the results. It was 95% accurate when a result was found but I did realized that around 20% percent of the files that were recognized by the single best match were identify as part of a compilation album while someone will think that the default best single match will be to identify the song as part of a single,an album of the artist when applicable before being identify as being part of a compilation album, an EP or a soundtrack album.

After looking at the documentation, I didn't see anything that let me configure that .
My suggestion will be to have a property that can be set in the config object similar to the "content.coverArt.sizePreference" property that is used to specify the covert art size preference.
That property will look like this : "content.singleBestMatch.albumPreference" and the different values will be something like "SINGLE, ALBUM, COMPILATION, DJ_MIX, SOUNDTRACK, LIVE_ALBUM"

I will be happy to hear comments from someone of the Gracenote team on this or anybody else.

Comment: Just an FYI that Gracenote has read your suggestion and are discussing it internally. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @jmctodo thanks. It's been a month and I started wondering if you guys were actually looking at thoses stackoverflow questions lol. I have also posted another question/suggestion I have posted [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021798/configuration-property-to-specify-after-how-many-milliseconds-the-recognizemidf) . Hopefully I can get an answer for that one too :)