# Configuration property to specify after how many milliseconds the "recognizeMIDFileFromFile" should start fingerprinting

Tags: gracenote

as the title says , I think it will be nice if there was config property that we can set in order to specify after how many milliseconds(or seconds ) the fingerprinting should be done on the file. According to the documentation, it is done at the start of the song but after playing for a while with the "
GNOperations.recognizeMIDFileFromFile" method, I did realized that some songs that couldn't be identified where strangely identifiable by "
GNOperations.recognizeMIDStreamFromMic" method. I did noticed that those songs that couldn't be identified had some special dj sound effects at the beginning of the song that were present on the original release of the song. My guess is the fact that fingerprinting did failed because it was starting at the beginning of the file instead of starting 5 or 10 seconds after the beginning of the file.

I will be nice to hear comment from someone of the Gracenote team on that feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting use case.

I assume you meant that the dj sound effects were *not* present in the original song?

MIDFile is designed to match high quality files sourced from CDs or downloads. Unless the dj tracks you have are in our File fingerprint DB as is, they won't be recognized by MIDFile. MIDFile truly operates on the beginning of files only, so delaying the start of fingerprinting is not likely to solve your problem (and will instead result in zero matches unless you were extremely accurate (and lucky) in choosing your start position).

However, MIDStream is able to recognize the audio snippet from later in the file as our Stream DB operates on the whole of the audio for a song.

The real solution is for the dj tracks to be added to our File DB (assuming they are commercially available) or to instead use MIDStream to recognize the song within the larger track.

Comment: Thanks @jmctodo for the quick reply :) I saw that api and I was trying to use it but I have not been able to find a java android library that does pcm sample of an mp3 file. I guess I will have no choice than use a C library instead.

Comment: On a side note, I read the documentation trying to find a way to get the exact release date using an albumId. Do you guys have the exact release date and just decided to exposed the release date? I think the release date is a precious information that can be use by developers to give programatic recommendation to users. It will be really really nice  if that information was exposed in the GNSearchResponse object :)

Comment: are you asking why you only get year instead of a month/day/year combo? if yes, then I think this is due to limitations in the sources of our data. often the exact date is unknown and labels and such don't have it any more granular than the year.

Comment: Yes I was asking if if was just a limitation in the sources of your data or a deliberated design decision. Last question , I know you guys are working on music recommendation platform similar to echonest, is that coming soon ?

Comment: it is probably a design decision to be consistent and use the lowest common denominator (i.e. year) so that folks don't have to worry what form the date will be?  Not exactly sure.  and do you mean this? https://www.gracenote.com/rhythm/

Comment: Yeah gracenote.com/rhythm that is what I was talking about . It was supposed to be available in February. I was just wondering what was the expected timeframe for that service.

Comment: It isn't my area of expertise, but it sure looks like it is live. if not, I can find out a date for you. https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api

Comment: my bad . you are right . It is actually out. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: I am sorry if I piggy back on this question but I was wondering what were the different values for the  "content.link.preferredSource" configuration parameter. I have tried "Deezer" but I am not sure if it is actually working or not.Does that configuration also influence the fileId/DirectoryID feature? I will also like my developer key to be entitled to retrieve artist information which can't retrieve at the moment. Can please tell me who I should contact? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: for the preferred source to work, you need to have your client ID entitled for the 3rd party IDs you want and then you need to know what the right string is to enter for those IDs. both of these require contact with us. to get in touch, I would recommend posting on the Gracenote Open Developer forums. From there we can reach out to you directly.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I will do that

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I was wondering if there was a way to get the list of all top music genres(level-0) used by the GNResultReady Object GNSearchResultReady Object... We are trying to map them with the music genres that we are using internally.